# How to get an attribute parameter in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code. I am trying to inject the `name` from the `myController` scope inside the `myObj` directive as a `nameAttr` attribute.

I've assigned the `name: '=nameAttr'` on the directive's scope, but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

https://plnkr.co/edit/qceVMl0w2gv03ZuQVQb8?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<my-obj nameAttr="name"></my-obj>
```

**INSIDE THE 'MY-OBJ.HTML'**

```
<h2>{{ name }}</h2>
<ol>
  <li ng-repeat="(slug, val) in loop">{{ slug }} - {{ val }}</li>
</ol>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
var mod = angular.module('myApp', []);

mod.controller('myController', myController).directive('myObj', myObject);

function myController($scope){
  $scope.name = 'John Smith';
}

function myObject(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'my-obj.html',
    scope: {
      name: '=nameAttr'
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.loop = {
        'one': 'gfshfh',
        'two': '32435'
      };
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: and where are you using name????

Comment: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `index.html` you need to write

`<my-obj name-attr="name"></my-obj>`

------------------^

`Directives` with `camelCase` names must be written as `camel-case` in your templates

Answer (score 1):

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> ```
> Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
> Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.
> ```

Directive documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)